# Java 3D Engine Pixel Drawing Problems

Tags: java

my 3 programs seem to work alone but when I try to run them together It seems to give me an out of bounds error but I cant tell where exactly if anyone can tell me where exactly it is and how to fix the error that would be great, I wanted to use a debugger but im having some problems getting it to work.

Here is my Code for the 3 Classes : 
    Render.java
    package com.mime.Game.graphics;

```
public class Render {
public final int width;
public final int height;
public final int[] pixels;

public Render(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}
public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for(int x = 0; x < this.height; x++) {
        int yPix = x + yOffset;
        for(int y = 0; y < this.width; y++) {
            int xPix = y + xOffset;

            pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = render.pixels[x + y * 
render.width];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Display.java 
    package com.mime.Game;

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mime.Game.graphics.Render;
import com.mime.Game.graphics.Screen;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable{
public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

private Thread thread;
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage img;
private boolean running = false;
private Render render;
private int[] pixels;

public Display() {
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}

private void start() {
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

    System.out.println("Working");
}
public void stop() {
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);


    }
}
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        tick();
        render();
    }
}
private void tick() {

}
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    screen.render();
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Chronicles of Walshy Alpha 0.01");

    game.start();
}

}
```

screen.java : 
    package com.mime.Game.graphics;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Screen extends Render{

private Render test;

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
    Random random = new Random();
    test = new Render(256, 256);
    for(int i = 0; i < 256*256; i++) {
        test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
    }

}
public void render() {
    draw(test, 0, 0);
}

}
```

Comment: _"It seems to give me an out of bounds error"_ What do you mean, _"it seems"_? Does it give you an error or not? _"but I cant tell where exactly"_ Why not? Exceptions in Java have a stacktrace that tell you **exactly** where they happened.

Comment: Thanks a ton for noticing, although I am getting an out of bounds error the reason I cant tell where is because the line it all adds up on uses multiple variables to create the number, so I have more than one place it can start at, to be more specific the actual line is " pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = render.pixels[x + y * render.width];"

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough in the original question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing information, including the full error message and stacktrace. It's not good when people have to look for essential information in the comments.

Comment: `int yPix = x + yOffset;` `int xPix = y + xOffset;` <-- Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Render.draw` method you copy pixels from another `Render` object and you use `this.width` and `this.height` to access those pixels. This will fail when the other `Render` object's pixel size is smaller, which is the case in your code. You get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when reading from `render.pixels[x + y * render.width]` because you're trying to read pixels from a `256*256` array as if it was a `800*600` array.

Additionally if you ever call `draw` with offset values, you will get another `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, because you're simply adding the offsets to your `x` and `y` values without checking if the resulting index is too big when writing to `pixels[xPix + yPix * width]`.

To fix this, you have to skip any value that goes beyond the width or height of either `pixels` array:

```
if (xPix > this.width || yPix > this.height || x > render.width || y > render.height)
{
  continue;
}
```